# Play individually split video files in android {used java for splitting}

Tags: java, android, video

I'm working on an android project which needs me to split a video file into some parts(like each of 5 mb) and then individually playing these parts.
I have successfully split the video into the parts but these parts are not playing.(maybe missing some playing attributes identified by the player).
If someone could provide the solution as to how to play these individual parts without merging(necessary for my project) in context of code only. ps. cannot use any third party software as making an android app.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView.setText("Successfull");
                    splitFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testing1/video.mp4"));
                }
            }
    );
}

public static void splitFile(File f) {
    int partCounter = 1;//I like to name parts from 001, 002, 003, ...
    //you can change it to 0 if you want 000, 001, ...

    int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 1024 * 10;// 10MB
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];

    try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(f))) {//try-with-resources to ensure closing stream
        String name = f.getName();

        int tmp = 0;
        while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            //write each chunk of data into separate file with different number in name
            File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), name + "."
                    + String.format("%03d", partCounter++)+".mp4");
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile)) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just splitting the binary file into parts. A video file is encoded in a special format, using a program called a codec. If you want your chunks to be playable, you have to make sure they are also properly formatted, according to the original codec.

Maybe you can have a look at something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35605/splitting-an-mp4-file). It shows how to split a video file into playable chunks using `ffmpeg`. If it is available on Android, you may try and use it as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is never going to work this way. What you are essentially doing is simply splitting a binary file into parts. An `mp4` video (or any format for that matter) has its data encoded in a specific format and simply breaking the file into parts will not split the video itself. It will instead render the parts unreadable (read: unplayable). The initial bytes in a video file will generally consist of the metadata about the video file. You'll have to read about the MP4 format specifications and will have to write an encoder/decoder (which will not be a cup of tea).

You will be better off using a library to split the video files.